# getting the name of file

Tags: symfony

I am using Synfony 2.1. I have a form where I pass a jpg.file

How to get the name of the file!

I try with getOriginalName() but don´t work.

this is my form

```
public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nombre');
    $builder->add('descripcion', 'textarea');
    $builder->add('valor');
    $builder->add('imagen', 'file', array('required' => false));
```

and I try to get the value as...

```
  if ($form->isValid()){
               ...
                $imagen= $gift->getImagen();
                $filename =$imagen->getOriginalName();
                $ruta='\web\stories\/'. $filename;
```

any idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `getClientOriginalName()`

Comment: It's always those little typos that have you pulling out your hair. Glad I could help!